# Use CrossProfileApps to run app on managed profile

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a application which needs to be run from my smartphone's work profile. I've read Google's documentation on work profile and, specificaly,the [CrossProfileApps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/CrossProfileApps#getTargetUserProfiles()) class, which, in theory, allows the app to run under a specific user profile. I am able to list the profiles:

```
List<UserHandle> userProfiles = userManager.getUserProfiles();
```

But I didn't figured out a way (and neither does the Google documentation shows) how to use and access the `CrossProfileApps` methods. The class constructor isn't public, so I cannot just

```
CrossProfileApps foo = new CrossProfileApps();
```

And neither are these methods static to do such:

```
var foo = CrossProfileApps().fooMethod();
```

Getting to the bottom of my question: how do I make use of the CrossProfileApps class and use it's methods in order to run my app or a single activity under a specified user profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's

```
CrossProfileApps crossProfileApps = (CrossProfileApps) context.getSystemService(Context.CROSS_PROFILE_APPS_SERVICE);
```

Also make sure you're on API 28 or higher